# Change pane of existing tileLayer in Leaflet interactively

Tags: leaflet, tile-layer

I'm developing a map application in Leaflet with multiple Layers (Tile-Layer and TopoJSON). I would like a button, which moves the Tile-Layer in front of the other Layers. Therefore I need to put the Tile-Layer into a pane with a z-Index > 400 (see [Map Panes](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tilelayer)). This works fine when initializing the Tile-Layer, but how do I move an existing Tile-layer into another pane in the foreground after having initialised it (change "pane: 'tilePane'" to "pane: 'layerForeground'")?

```
map.createPane('layerForeground');
map.getPane('layerForeground').style.zIndex = 650;

var SWEmean71_00Apr =L.tileLayer('data/maps/e01_swe/tiles/3857_Mittelwert/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 12,
minZoom: 7,
tms: false,
pane: 'tilePane',
})//.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet layers can **not** change panes dynamically. Panes are too tightly coupled to the initialization of the `HTMLElement`s for the layers' containers.

You can, however, change the `zIndex` of a map pane dynamically. So you can set a unique pane for each of your tilelayers, and change their z-indexes when you need to change their order.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!!